# Fatal error: session_start():

Tags: php, magento, localhost

When I migrated magento store and run it locally this happens.

Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: C:\wamp\www\magento\var\session) in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php on line 115

This is line 115: session_start();

Help please.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, **core_session** table is missing in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Look into your php.ini and make sure that the save_path isn't commented or missing:

```
session.save_path = "C:\wamp\tmp"
```

Create the folder `C:\wamp\tmp` first, change php.ini, then restart wamp.

Comment: I already have C:\wamp\tmp folder and also in my php.ini this line already exist and uncommented
session.save_path = "C:\wamp\tmp"
Same error.

Comment: Try adding ini_set('session.save_path',  'C:\wamp\tmp'); before session_start(); in your script.